# PHP if isset $_POST - echo Jumping in and out of html and php

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm trying to make a button so when i click It will show content from sql SELECT inside of a table with use of if and isset.

I know i have to jump in and out of html and php by using  ' ' and " " but i dont know in which order.

```
 include 'connect.php';
 <form method="post">
     <button type="submit" name="vis_alle">Vis alle</button>
     </form>

 <?php 

 if (isset($_POST['vis_alle'])) {

   echo "

   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <tr>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>navn</th> 
       <th>farve</th>
       <th>vægt (g)</th>
       <th>smags-surhed</th>
       <th>smags-styrke</th>
       <th>smags-type</th>
       <th>råvarepris (øre)</th>
     </tr>

     <?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM bolcher";

     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

     while ($bolcheliste = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

       $id = $bolcheliste['id'];
       $navn = $bolcheliste['navn'];
       $farve = $bolcheliste['farve'];
       $vaegt_gram = $bolcheliste['vaegt_gram'];
       $smags_surhed = $bolcheliste['smag_surhed'];
       $smag_styrke = $bolcheliste['smag_styrke'];
       $smags_type = $bolcheliste['smags_type'];
       $raavarepris_oere = $bolcheliste['raavarepris-oere'];

       ?>

       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $navn; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $farve; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $vaegt_gram; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $smags_surhed; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $smag_styrke; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $smags_type; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $raavarepris_oere; ?></td>
       </tr>

       <?php
     }
     ?>
   </table>
   ";
 }
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?  Your first line looks like a PHP statement but you appear to be in HTML there.  An important thing to remember... PHP runs on the server to produce an HTML output, generally.

Comment: You seem to miss the basics of php and html integration. For example: have you ever heard of ?> closing tag for php? Or of the difference between single and double quotes? Better do some training before starting programming. Plus 1 only because you're not using misql but misqly

Comment: Error: `echo "

  <table class="` You need to escape quotes in strings when the same quote is used for encapsulation. `include 'connect.php';` should be inside of  `<?php`.

Answer (score 2):

You have your echo statement printing PHP blocks, which won't work. You need to close your echo before running any PHP. Or do something like this:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>

<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="vis_alle">Vis alle</button>
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['vis_alle'])) { ?>

  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>navn</th> 
      <th>farve</th>
      <th>vægt (g)</th>
      <th>smags-surhed</th>
      <th>smags-styrke</th>
      <th>smags-type</th>
      <th>råvarepris (øre)</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bolcher";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($bolcheliste = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $id = $bolcheliste['id'];
      $navn = $bolcheliste['navn'];
      $farve = $bolcheliste['farve'];
      $vaegt_gram = $bolcheliste['vaegt_gram'];
      $smags_surhed = $bolcheliste['smag_surhed'];
      $smag_styrke = $bolcheliste['smag_styrke'];
      $smags_type = $bolcheliste['smags_type'];
      $raavarepris_oere = $bolcheliste['raavarepris-oere'];

      ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $navn; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $farve; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $vaegt_gram; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $smags_surhed; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $smag_styrke; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $smags_type; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $raavarepris_oere; ?></td>
      </tr>

      <?php } ?>
  </table>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is possible while switching between php and html:

```
<?php #lets set a variable in php 
$arg = "<b>World</b>";
/* colse php */?>
<!-- html part -->
<div>Hello Html <?=$arg;?></div>
<!-- html part end, open php again -->
<?php #php code again, and print some too
echo "<div>Hello PHP $arg</div>";
#or
echo '<div>Hello PHP '.$arg.', again!</div>';
?>
<!--or just -->
<?="<div>Year, $arg</div>";?>
<!-- shorthand of:<?php echo "<div>Year, $arg</div>"; ?>  -->
```

Impossible is:

```
<?php echo "<b><?php echo "World";?></b>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answers, there are more efficient ways of integrating your code into HTML (though common wisdom is that separating them entirely is best.)

Important to remember, which are the basic problems you're having: anything between `<?php` and `?>` is PHP code. Likewise, anything inside an `echo` statement is treated as output to the screen.

```
<?php include 'connect.php';?>

<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="vis_alle">Vis alle</button>
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['vis_alle'])): ?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>navn</th> 
        <th>farve</th>
        <th>vægt (g)</th>
        <th>smags-surhed</th>
        <th>smags-styrke</th>
        <th>smags-type</th>
        <th>råvarepris (øre)</th>
    </tr>

 <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bolcher";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while ($bolcheliste = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id               = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['id']);
        $navn             = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['navn']);
        $farve            = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['farve']);
        $vaegt_gram       = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['vaegt_gram']);
        $smags_surhed     = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['smag_surhed']);
        $smag_styrke      = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['smag_styrke']);
        $smags_type       = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['smags_type']);
        $raavarepris_oere = htmlspecialchars($bolcheliste['raavarepris-oere']);
        echo <<< HTML
    <tr>
        <td>$id</td>
        <td>$navn</td>
        <td>$farve</td>
        <td>$vaegt_gram</td>
        <td>$smags_surhed</td>
        <td>$smag_styrke</td>
        <td>$smags_type</td>
        <td>$raavarepris_oere</td>
    </tr>
HTML;
    } // end while
    echo "</table>";
endif;
?>
```

A couple of little tricks, to give you some ideas.

When mixing PHP and HTML, using the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) can make things easier to follow, which I did with the first `if` statement. Rather than having a random `<?php } ?>` at the bottom of a page, you get `<?php endif; ?>`. (Of course, commenting helps that as well.)

Another nice feature when echoing lots of HTML with PHP inside it is the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which I used to echo the table row. It allows parsing of PHP variables inside the output, but also you don't have to worry about escaping quote marks.

And always, always, remember to [escape your output](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before putting it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments in the code its should work

```
<?php
  include 'connect.php'; // you had forgotten to put it in PHP Tags
?>

  <form method="post">
      <button type="submit" name="vis_alle">Vis alle</button>
  </form>

 <?php 

 if (isset($_POST['vis_alle'])) {

   echo "

   <table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
     <tr>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>navn</th> 
       <th>farve</th>
       <th>vægt (g)</th>
       <th>smags-surhed</th>
       <th>smags-styrke</th>
       <th>smags-type</th>
       <th>råvarepris (øre)</th>
     </tr>"; // you have to end your echo here so you don`t have your while loop in it

     $query = "SELECT * FROM bolcher";

     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

     while ($bolcheliste = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

       $id = $bolcheliste['id'];
       $navn = $bolcheliste['navn'];
       $farve = $bolcheliste['farve'];
       $vaegt_gram = $bolcheliste['vaegt_gram'];
       $smags_surhed = $bolcheliste['smag_surhed'];
       $smag_styrke = $bolcheliste['smag_styrke'];
       $smags_type = $bolcheliste['smags_type'];
       $raavarepris_oere = $bolcheliste['raavarepris-oere'];

       ?>

       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $navn; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $farve; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $vaegt_gram; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $smags_surhed; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $smag_styrke; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $smags_type; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $raavarepris_oere; ?></td>
       </tr>

       <?php
     }
     ?>
   </table>
   <?php 
      } // you had forgotten the start PHP tag
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tiny heredoc alternative that maybe can be useful here.

https://gist.github.com/fcamp/c4cb828cfb22bbe845cb